# Indention Errors on Python IDLE

Tags: python, indentation

I'm just following the basic's of python and have been using IDLE as I find it handy to experiment scripts in real-time.

While I can run this script with no issues as a file I just cannot include the last print statement in IDLE!. I have tried an indentation, 4 spaces, no indentation's.  Please explain what I'm doing wrong.

```
while True:
    print ('Who are you?')
    name = input()
    if name != 'Joe':
        continue
    print('Hello, Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish.)')
    password = input()
    if password == 'swordfish':
        break
print('value')
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

You can type one statement at a time. The `while` loop considered one with the loop itself, and since the loop is a code block everything in it is okay.

The `print` at the end however is a new command. You have to run the `while` loop first and type the `print` after in the interpreter.

Comment: I thought that was the case. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can't paste more than one statement at a time into IDLE. The problem has nothing to do with indentation. The `while` loop constitutes one compound statement and the final `print` another.

The following also has issues when you try to paste at once into IDLE:

```
print('A')
print('B')
```

The fact that this has a problem shows even more clearly that the issue ins't one of indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have an undentation error in line 10, then you need just to add an espace

```
while True:
    print ('Who are you?')
    name = input()
    if name != 'Joe':
        continue
    print('Hello, Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish.)')
    password = input()
    if password == 'swordfish':
        break
    print('value')
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have kindly pointed out python IDLE only allows one block of code to be executed at a time. In this instance the while loop is a 'block'. The last print statement is outside this block thus it cannot be executed.